# Use @Gateway with Spring-Integration-Kafka

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration

Using Spring-Integration-Kafka can we still use @MessagingGateway and @Gateway.

My current code looks like this:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface OrderGateway {
 @Gateway(requestChannel = "requestChannel", replyChannel = "replyChannel",headers = {@GatewayHeader(name = "kafka_topic", value ="requestTopic"))
  Order order(Item item)
}
```

on my Spring Spring configuration:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestChannel")
public MessageHandler kafkaMessageHandler(KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate) {
    KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> messageHandler = new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<>(kafkaTemplate);
    messageHandler.setMessageKeyExpression(new LiteralExpression("spring-integration-kafka"));
    messageHandler.setTopicExpression(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("headers.kafka_topic"));
    return messageHandler;
}
```

with this setup I get and error saying:

```
by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to have shown the complete configuration.

The gateway is expecting a reply but the `kafkaMessageHandler` produces no reply (unless the template is a `ReplyingKafkaTemplate`) and will lose the `replyChannel` header.

So, presumably, you are trying to send a reply from someplace else.

If you are expecting request/reply semantics; use the [new outbound gateway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/_spring_integration.html#si-outbound-gateway).

Where the template has to be a `ReplyingKafkaTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks @Gary this fixed my issue